# Find first occurrence of a character before a keyword with Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to extract each first occurrence of a character before a keyword.
In the string below, the idea would be to extract the position of ">" just for lines that contain the word "Change", and should match 3 ">" on the 3 last lines.

```
<th class="col_heading level0 col5" >Thing</th>
<th class="col_heading level0 col6" >Second Thing</th>
<th class="col_heading level0 col7" >Third Thing</th>

<th class="col_heading level0 col5" >Thing Change</th>
<th class="col_heading level0 col6" >Second Thing Change</th>
<th class="col_heading level0 col7" >Third Thing Change</th>
```

I have a begin of answer, using look-alike operator, I'm currently able to extract text from the ">" to the "Change" Keyword, but I'm stuck to extract just the ">" properly

```
([^"]*(?=Change))
```

Comment: `>(?=.*Change)`? Or `>(?=[^<>]*Change)`? Or ``>(?=[^<>]*\bChange\b)`` See https://regex101.com/r/OKLti9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
>(?=.*?Change)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Vyimy2/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Change                   'Change'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```